# Create Installer out of .exe file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I let the Crypto Obfuscator run over my program and i got an .exe file with all DLLs and everything in it. Thats really great but i need to create an installer out of it.
It should cost no time and have a graphical UI!
Whats the best (free) way to do this?

Are there any programs?

Comment: NSIS, Wix, Advanced Installer, InstallShield, InnoSetup, ClickOnce, etc etc etc... Please do some research before asking.

Comment: All solutions you mentioned are more or less discussed and not that what i search for. But thx for your comment.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific feature ? if so then please mention what you're looking for in an installer software.

Comment: Yes i edited my requirements. Its just for test cases, cost not time and money and should be as easy to use as possible (graphical UI). Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions:

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) are popular free and open source *scripted* installer creators.

If you prefer having a graphical interface, the free InstallSimple and Clickteam's Install Creator are common choices.

For more alternatives, Wikipedia has a page entitled "List of installation software" providing a decent overview of what's available.

(Sorry about the lack of hyperlinks - the site's spam prevention system won't allow me to post more.)

Comment: Yes thats what i did search for. I mean the free graphical interface solutions (maybe i should have mentioned this ^^) Thank you so much!

Comment: What i use now is HM NIS EDIT http://hmne.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Its in Visual Studio :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx

Comment: yeah but its not free and i have the problem that with crypto obfuscator i get the .exe out from my release build after running it. how can i make an install file OUT OF THIS .EXE ? Where i can say what the installer should set in registry and so on.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, what's the problem? It's like saying you can't rely on the computer having Windows since it's not free, but it's supposed to run at Windows. It's no problem making an installer in Visual Studio, it's included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Comment: Thx for this real fast answer, but i have no idea how to use this. I would also prefer a visual studio plugin and not to switch between IDEs only for creating installer. Maybe its totally easy, but really dont know what to do with this. :/